# Node Express. Continue function execution after res.render

Tags: node.js, express, render

It is necessary to build the page and then continue the execution of the function, which takes a lot of time. But res.render waits for the function to execute no matter where it is called.
I want the page to start building without waiting for the data to be processed.
Here is my code:

```
        let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            let wb = new Workbook();
            let ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(public_data); //May take up to 5 seconds
            wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
            wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
            XLSX.writeFile(wb, '/tmp/' + name); //May take up to 10 seconds
            resolve('End of promise!!!');
        })
        res.render('ihelp/lists/person_selection_view_data', {
            data: public_data,
            name
        });
        promise.then(answer => { console.log(answer) });
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Try to add `return`

Comment: is your handler function async?

Comment: Why don't you render before starting the promise?

Comment: You can't make blocking code non-blocking just by wrapping it with `Promise`. If you want to run blocking code without blocking the rest of your app, use [worker threads](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html).

Comment: @NewUser2, i tried adding `return`, it doesn't work.

Comment: AndréAlçadaPadez, no, sync

Comment: @Charlie, i tried and it didn't work

Comment: @robertklep, I tried to run the code synchronously after calling `render`. But the render is still waiting for this code to execute. I do not understand why. I will get acquainted with `Worker threads`, thanks.

Comment: The reason is that you're blocking the event loop, or at least it looks like it with the code that you're showing. Since `res.render()` is asynchronous, it will get blocked, even if you start the synchronous (blocking) code after it.

Comment: @robertklep, please post this as an answer. I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code that you want to run looks to be synchronous (I don't see any promises or callbacks related to it). If it takes multiple seconds to run, that will mean that it will block your entire app for that amount of time.

This means that asynchronous functions, like `res.render()`, will not complete until the processing is done. Even if you change the order:

```
res.render(...);
long_running_code();
```

Not only will this not make `res.render()` send back a response *before* `long_running_code` is started, it will also stop your app from responding to new incoming requests (and/or block any current requests) until it's done.

If you have CPU-intensive code that will block the event look, take a look at [`worker_threads`](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html), which can be used to offload CPU-intensive code to separate threads, and therefore keep your main JS thread free to handle the HTTP-part of your app.

Answer (score 0):

The `res.render` takes a 3rd argument for a callback. If supplied, Express will not send the rendered html string automatically. Any extended process  can be executed after that.

```
res.render('ihelp/lists/person_selection_view_data', {data: public_data, name}, function (err, html) {

  res.send(html);    

  let wb = new Workbook();
  let ws = sheet_from_array_of_arrays(public_data); //May take up to 5 seconds
  wb.SheetNames.push(ws_name);
  wb.Sheets[ws_name] = ws;
  XLSX.writeFile(wb, '/tmp/' + name); //May take up to 10 seconds   


})
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work. The page is still not built until the functions after `res.send(html)` are executed

Answer (score 0):

The executor function (inside the Promise constructor) is executed synchronously, and if this takes too long, you can move it into another Promise:

```js
res.render('ihelp/lists/person_selection_view_data', {
  data: public_data,
  name
});
Promise.resolve().then(function() {
  new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // your executor code
  }).then(answer => { console.log(answer) });
});
```